# XML - JavaScript -> How to display XML tags as HTML

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

*The problem I have is that when an XML node has no value, the open and close tags are on different rows like this*

```
<td ID="ref_4b73aa95ffd2289_phrPayer_1_DateEffective">
</td>
<td ID="ref_4b73aa95ffd2289_phrPayer_1_DateTerminated">
</td>
```

*and when the node has data, the open and close tags are on one line:*

```
<td ID="ref_4b73ba85ffd2289_phrPayer_1_Company">Medicare Parts A&amp;B</td>
```

**The problem I have is that when I read the data, it is read line by line. 
Following is the XML data that is used:**

```
 <tr>
     <td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_Company">Medicare Parts A&amp;B</td>
     <td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_DateEffective">
     </td>
     <td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_DateTerminated">
     </td>
     <td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_PolicyNumber">
     </td>
     <td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_GroupNumber">
     </td>
     <td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_SubscriberName">AdamJulie</td>
 </tr>
```

**Above coding consistes of 6 columns, although as displayed above, there are 10 lines of coding. That is the main problem. **

When I try to split up the data into an `Array` using the ***following***:

```
var purposeArray = purposeOfVisit.innerHTML.split("\n");
```

**The data I receive is:**

```
Medicate Parts A&amp;B,,,,,,,,,AdamJulie
```

**when it should be:**

```
Medicare Parts A&amp;B,,,,,AdamJulie
```

The length of the array is the same as the number of lines which is 10 in this case, where it should be 5.

*What I want to know is how I read the `td` tags with the data*.

***I want the innerHTML to read the folling code as an example:***

```
<td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_Company">Medicare Parts A&amp;B</td>
<td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_DateEffective">
</td>
<td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_DateTerminated">
</td>
<td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_PolicyNumber">
</td>
<td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_GroupNumber">
</td>
<td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_SubscriberName">AdamJulie</td>
```

*instead of:*

```
Medicare Parts A&amp;B
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
AdamJulie
```

The `.` Represents a null value.

Is this possible and if it is how would I do this? or to replace the `<td>` tags with `&lt;<td>` and `</td>` tags with `</td>&lt;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe check [Sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/) library out.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of using an XML parser in such a manner**, you can read in an xml string via a stream like so:

```
var XMLString = "<tbody><tr><td ID=''>Medicare Parts A&amp;B</td><td ID=''></td><td ID=''></td><td ID=''></td><td ID=''></td><td ID=''>AdamJulie</td></tr><tr><td ID=''>Test2</td><td ID=''></td><td ID=''></td><td ID=''>123</td><td ID=''></td><td ID=''></td></tr></tbody>";
```

Where you can `split` the string after each column:

```
myXMLArray = XMLString .split("</td>");
```

And use a regular Expression to remove all tags.

```
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;

for( var x = 0; x < XMLString .length; x++)
{
result[x] = XMLString [x].replace(regex, "");
}
```

*Goodluck...*

Answer (score 0):

The innerHTML method returns whatever lies inside the HTML-tag. If you want to fetch the HTML tag with the data, i suggest you use something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('td')
```

Comment: The reason for the innerHTML is that I am using `<xsl:value-of  select="ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component/section/text/table/tbody"/>` to get the data. These tags are stored inside of the div "purposeOfVisit".

Comment: Im a little confused. You said you wanted innerHTML to read "<td ID="ref__phrPayer_1_Company">Medicare Parts A&amp;B</td>" instead of "Medicare Parts A&amp;B". This is not possible, innerHTML will not read that. Im also unsure where xslt comes into this picture, but maybe what you want is to add `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to that value of?

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have gone a bit more into depth of what I want. The xsl file is necessary to convert the xml file. Th eXML file is not merely used as a SataSource, it is used to generate the entire webpage. Seeing that the `<xsl>` tags are inside the div, I want the `<xsl>` to get as above explained. To get The data with the tags. The innerHTML will then get all data inside the div, including the `<td>` tags. I am not sure whether this is a roundabout method to doing this, seeing that I am kind of new to xml and xslt. I have found that `disable-output-escaping="yes"` makes no changes

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write your own XML parser, and you are doing it wrong. You can't simply split XML at line boundaries and then parse each line separately.

There are plenty of good XML parsers available, and it's best to use one of them. If you must parse the XML yourself, then you need to study the art of parser-writing; it's not a job for amateurs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then I'll be looking for an XML parser :)